# Remove the vertical spacers in a td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

What is the best way to remove the last occurrence of the element spacer (|) from this td using jQuery?

```html
 <td class="actionCol" nowrap=""><a href="#xyz">XYZ</a> | <a href="#err">ERR</a> | <a href="#PING">PING</a></td>
```

Comment: Remove all occurrences?

Comment: Actually there is an answer for removing all occurrences but I just want to remove the last occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to remove only the last occurrence, you may do the following.

```
$('.actionCol').html(function(_, elem) {
    return elem.replace(/\|(?!.*\|)/, '');
});
```

[**A Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vc63n2r7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the last occurrence using `substr`. No need to use `regex`, this will be faster than `regex`.

```js
$('.actionCol').html(function(i, e) {
  var lastIndex = e.lastIndexOf('|');
  return e.substr(0, lastIndex) + e.substr(lastIndex + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td class="actionCol" nowrap=""><a href="#xyz">XYZ</a> | <a href="#err">ERR</a> | <a href="#PING">PING</a>
  </td>
</table>
```